# Dynamically add Link Label in windows form app

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I'm trying to draw a Text message on a windows form using the following code:

```
e.Graphics.DrawString(message_type_show[cont_position], Parent.TitleFont, brushTitle, titleX + 5, Parent.HeaderHeight + Parent.TitlePadding.Top + (spacing * cont_position));
```

`e.Graphics.DrawString`works fine and I'm able to see the text. Is there any to add a link to the added text message.

Comment: Since you just *drawing* this text on the form - the only way for you to add link in this manner - is to manually draw some text underlined, handle `MouseMove` event, change mouse cursor to "pointing finger" then cursor is over your "link", handle `Click` event and execute something you need when click occured in your "link" rectangle. Alternative to this approach - is now to draw all this stuff manually, but use label controls with appropriate look and feed and click event handlers.

Comment: If you want a link label, why not use the [LinkLabel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Can you elaborate a bit more. I'm quite new to winforms app ...

Comment: Unless you have some particular need for graphical elements drawn manually, you should abandon your approach.  Use the controls available to you.  If this is a WinForms application, use the [LinkLabel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel(v=vs.110).aspx) control.  If you are doing an asp.net page, use [HyperLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx).  Just place the controls using the designer.